# AJAX load-eventlistener fires before getting response from server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, submit

I'm writing an snippet to upload images through AJAX. A user selects the image in a form file-input. The form has a onsubmit-function which prevents default, so that the page doesn't reload after submitting. In this function the formdata is captured and than send through a XMLHttpRequest which has some event listeners appended. Also the "load"-eventlistener. This "load"-function consists of things like hiding a loader and echo something like "finished uploading". The page where the data is transmitted through ajax has a php-script which scales the image, copy it, rename it and so on. To it creates various copies in different sizes of the image.

The Problem: If I submit the form NOT through ajax, everything is fine. The php-needs some seconds, till everything is saved and the page is loaded. Through Ajax, directly after submitting the form, it says "finished", but the php-script is not executed! It feels like AJAX stops PHP running the script. The "load"-function IS FIRED! But way to early! Almost directly after submitting...

Here's the JS-Code:

```
loader("show");
window.event.preventDefault();
var data = $(form).serializeArray();
var src = form.getAttribute("action");
$.post( src, data )
.done(function( data ) {
    loader("hide");
});
```

I have also tested with clean JS, but same problem:

```
var formdata = $(form).serializeArray();
var page = form.getAttribute("action");
loader(show);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event) { completeHandler(event);}, false);
ajax.open("POST",page);
ajax.send(formdata);
```

completeHandler:

```
function completeHandler ( evt ) {
    alert("finished");
    loader("hide");
}
```

Thanks for help! :)

**EDIT:** The HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="create.php" onSubmit="uploadForm(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file1" type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: _"The php-needs some seconds, "_ How many seconds ?

Comment: I believe you need to specify multipart form data when uploading a file... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342506/why-is-form-encrtype-multipart-form-data-required-when-uploading-a-file

Comment: PHP needs about 5 seconds...

Comment: How is this ajax code being triggered? Is it in a function called by some event? Can you show that information?

Comment: @OliverJ90: I used multipart/form-data on the form.

Comment: @epascarello: Added HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the reason why it is being fired too quickly is you are not canceling the default action of whatever is triggering the function. You either need to call `preventDefault` or `return false` to stop the default action from causing the page to exit which aborts the Ajax calls.

```
function uploadForm () {
//function uploadForm (event) {   
    //event.preventDefault();  //cancel the default action
    loader("show");
    //window.event.preventDefault();  <-- get rid of this
    var data = $(form).serializeArray();
    var src = form.getAttribute("action"); 
    $.post( src, data )
    .done(function( data ) {
        loader("hide");
    });
    //or
    return false;
}
```

---

EDIT:

You posted you are calling it `onsubmit` so you need to cancel the submission. Add the `return` to the `onsubmit` and the above `return false` from your method.

```
<form onSubmit="return uploadForm(this)" ...>
```

Comment: That's not the problem. The page doesn't reload on submit. That's all working. I just don't copy the event.preventDefault() in the "normal JS"-version

Comment: Not all browsers have `window.event...` Are you testing in just IE?

Comment: Do the return false and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I added both. The return false in the function and in the unsubmti-attribute. But it makes no difference. I'm working with firefox and safari.

Comment: So are there error messages in the console? (You need to click the "preserve log" checkbox)

Comment: NO. There's nothing. :/

Comment: Did you remove the `window.event.preventDefault();`? If you look at the textStatus `.done(function( data, textStatus )` what does it say when you log it?

Comment: It says "success". If I remove the image-processing from the php-file, I can access the output (data) of the php-file. But not, if I let the script work with the image...