# Django.form dont get file from request in its field image

Tags: python, django, forms, file

I have django modelForm from model with FileField

```
class A(models.Model):
     image = models.FileFiled(null=True, upload_to='images/', verbose_name='name')

class Form(forms.Form):
     model = A
```

In views i get file from Post request

```
def edit(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(A,pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
```

But image in object didn't change,it is unobviosly for me,because this form,but for creating objects,work fine
How can i solve this problem in an easy way?

Comment: do you ever save the form? or check if its valid?

Comment: yes,of course,in this object all fields change except FileField

Answer (score 1):

In the form you need to have `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

For more details you can check [Why is form enctype=multipart/form-data required when uploading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342506/why-is-form-enctype-multipart-form-data-required-when-uploading-a-file)

Comment: i have this string in form