# "Undefined index: data" error in php

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have the following form that allows user to upload the image:

```
<form name='form1' method="POST" action="" id="registration_form">
<input type="file" name="data" id="data">
<input type="Submit" name="Upload1" value="Upload1">
</form>
```

And following php code that does the actual upload:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Upload1']))
{
$errors=array();
$allowed_ext= array('pdf','jpg','jpeg');
$file_name =$_FILES['data']['name']; //error shows in this line
$file_ext = strtolower( end(explode('.',$file_name)));

$file_size=$_FILES['data']['size'];
$file_tmp= $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];

$type = pathinfo($file_tmp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($file_tmp);

if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext) === false){
    $errors[]='Extension not allowed';
}

if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]= 'File size must be under 2mb';
}
if(empty($errors))
{
   if( move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'images/'.$file_name));
   {
    $ct='application/' .$file_ext.'<br/>' ;
    $base64 =  base64_encode($data);        

    //json part is here 
   }
}
else {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error , '<br/>'; 
    }
}
```

}

When I select the file and hit "UPLOAD", it shows error as "Undefined index: data". But what is interesting to note is that 1 out of 10 times, it works! Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: It shows: array(0) { }

Comment: Is your file field name is data? Or u forgot to add form multipart

Comment: If it's showing empty than u forgot to add form multipart. Chk are u using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside the form tag?

Comment: even in using    enctype="multipart/form-data", var_dump($_FILES); is showing array(0) { }

Comment: Using JavaScript for submit form? If yes than u must need to use formData becuaee you r using file input

Comment: I am using javascript for input validation when the user submits the form. Else the actual submit is done in php only. So should I need to use formData?

Comment: accepting the correct answer will help to future visitors

Answer (score 0):

According to your form you are not using multiparty/form-data in form tag.

You just need to use

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Inside the form tag for input type file.

**Example**:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

***Why it's needed?*** [Why is form enctype=multipart/form-data required when uploading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342506/why-is-form-enctype-multipart-form-data-required-when-uploading-a-file)

If you are using JavaScript for submit the form than you can use formData for getting data from input either post or file.

```
var formData = new FormData(formId);
```

Comment: My complete form is :    
    <form name='suomotu_registration' method="POST" action="" id="registration_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return formValidation();">    

var_dump($_FILES); 
displays 
array(0) { }

Comment: nope I am not using ajax. Actually I need to parse the user submitted form in json and send it to an API. I am familiar with php on doind this. so using php instead.

Comment: Than it will not control with normal way.. U must need to use `new formData` explore the formData this will help u @amir-bhandari

Comment: Ajax is only the solution here?

Comment: @amir-bhandari no u can use formData

Comment: Would you please enlighten more like with examples?

Comment: @amir-bhandari u can explore formData