# How to make an Asp.Net Core form with file upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iformfile

I am creating a registration form for a user, using a viewmodel. Besides entering data such as Username, email and password, the user must also upload an image.

When the user is finished entering the data and the viewmodel is send to the action method, something interesting happens.

The file is null, but all the other data is correct.

This is the viewmodel:

```
public class RegisterAsBusiness
{   
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Html part:

```
@model AfsluttendeProject.Models.ViewModels.RegisterAsBusiness


<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="RegisterAsBusiness">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <dl>
                    <dt>
                        <label asp-for="FormFile"></label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input asp-for="FormFile" type="file">
                    </dd>
                </dl>

            </div>

  <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the methods in the controller:

```
public IActionResult RegisterAsBusiness()
{
    return View(new RegisterAsBusiness());
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAsBusiness(RegisterAsBusiness registration)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Comment: this would be help full https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/05/file-upload-in-aspnet-core-mvc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
you should check [what it means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) and [why is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342506/why-is-form-enctype-multipart-form-data-required-when-uploading-a-file).