# Trying to add picture to registration form but receiving NULL in the database (ASP.NET 5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, registration, scaffolding

My goal is to create a scaffold form and modify it by adding an avatar option. I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0

I used Scaffold to get Register.cshtml and Register.cshtml.cs files. Also I use [bs-custom-file-input.js](https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-custom-file-input) library to put pictures into the form. I slightly modified scaffold-created files to add avatar option. But after adding a photo and finishing registration there is no pictures in my database attached to new user. I commented added code so you can find what I did there. Everything else is default and generated with scaffold. Can anybody tell what's wrong?

How the form looks like:

[image]

How the database looks like:

[image]

Register.cshtml

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}


<main class="container">
    <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                //PICTURE FIELD
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Avatar"></label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input asp-for="Input.Avatar" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Выберите файл</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <section>
                <h4>Use another service to register.</h4>
                <hr />
                @{
                    if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                    {
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                                for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                                    {
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                    }
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    }
                }
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script src="~/lib/bs-custom-file-input/dist/bs-custom-file-input.js"></script>
    <script>
        bsCustomFileInput.init()
    </script>
}
```

Register.cshtml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WEB_053503_Butkevich.Entities;

namespace WEB_053503_Butkevich.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        //private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            //Field for a picture
            [Required]
            public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                //Working with the picture
                if (Input.Avatar != null)
                {
                    user.AvatarImage = new byte[(int)Input.Avatar.Length];
                    await Input.Avatar.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(user.AvatarImage, 0, (int)Input.Avatar.Length);
                }
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    /*await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");*/

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser (just a class derived from IdentityUser with the AvatarImage slot):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WEB_053503_Butkevich.Entities
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public byte[] AvatarImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have a very strange solution for this thing.

I have a form in _Layout.cshtml. I totally forgot about it and I guess it don't even connected to the form of registration. But I just added argument `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to this form, and everything works now.

Hope I could save some time to you. Because I couldn't save mine.

Comment: That's not a strange solution, that's the solution (also why did you correct your question to reflect this answer baffles me) - however, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342506/why-is-form-enctype-multipart-form-data-required-when-uploading-a-file